# Is it possible to change the textContent value of an svg use element that is a clone of a text element?

Tags: javascript, svg, text, element

I have an svg text element that I have cloned with the use element.  Is there a way to change the text value of the use element clone so that it is different than the source element?  I tried the following with no success.

```
use2[i]=document.createElementNS(svgns, "use");
use2[i].setAttributeNS(xlinkns, "xlink:href", "#hsc");
use2[i].setAttribute("x", ((i+1)*45+45));
use2[i].setAttribute("y", "0");
use2[i].textContent=(useCount+3);
document.getElementById("redarrows").appendChild(use2[i]);
```

The browser dom explorer shows the use element to have a textContent of the useCount+3 value, but on the screen the use element still shows the textContnet of the source text element.

Here is the text element I am cloning.

```
<text id="hsc" x="52.5" y="137" font-family="'Utsaah'" font-size="21">1</text>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `<use>` is just a view of the underlying content (the thing the `<use>` points to). It has no content DOM of its own.

If you create content within the `<use>` element it will be ignored as you have seen.

If you want to have different content then you can always clone and attach it yourself using [element.cloneNode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode) but be careful not to create duplicate element ids.

Comment: The cloneNode worked great.  As soon as I created the clone, I removed the id attribute `use2[i]=document.getElementById("hsc").cloneNode();
          use2[i].removeAttribute("id");`